# Hyper-v create many (Default Switch) network connections

Tags: hyper-v, network-adapter, windows-10-v1809

I'm on Windows 10 1809 and Hyper-V Version: 10.0.17763.1

Whenever I try to open a window that needs to look at info about Hyper-V's network switches, for example "[Virtual Switch Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxdAB.png)" or when I open virtual machine settings it will load up virtual switch info too, 3 new network connections get created.

Not only can't I delete them (Hyper-V manages their creation and deletion) they slow down system exponentially.

Also no hacks or any intervention was made into Hyper-V settings, Hyper-V was straight up enabled in "Add or remove features" and after reboot I created new virtual machine, but that machine had no Internet then I went into investigation and I noticed that many network connections.

If I restart vvms (Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management) service then all network connections are deleted and new are created (3 for "Default Switch" and 1 for create by me "External Switch")

My Network Connections:

[image]

Comment: I am looking at my Hyper-V machine with both Hyper-V and WSL enabled and running and have only Wi-Fi (active), Ethernet (not active) and Bluetooth . Are you able to back up your guest machine, disable Hyper-V, restart and see it the superfluous connections disappear. Is Windows 10 fully up to date (V21H1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all the vEthernet (Default Switch) once and for all?](https://superuser.com/questions/1282014/how-to-remove-all-the-vethernet-default-switch-once-and-for-all). See also [Cannot remove HyperV vEthernet (Default Switch)](https://superuser.com/questions/1341310/cannot-remove-hyperv-vethernet-default-switch).

Comment: Hyper-V will auto-create a Default virtual adapter and one virtual adapter for every physical network interface, and I've only ever seen that many adapters when Hyper-V's switch manager encounters an issue in the Registry that prevents it from renaming its original adapters, however I haven't experienced that since ~2017ish.

Comment: @John The connections are not the problem, they will dissapear if i shut down hyper-v, but they will start appearing again whenever i try to interact with hyper-v's switches, and on every interaction 3 new connections are created.

Comment: @harrymc
I tried your solutions, yes it will remove connections but won't solve the problem of connections being created again. I would like to avoid ripping off "Default switch" with registry, i think it is not the root of the problem.

Comment: @JW0914
Thats strange, despite being able to create registry entries hyper-v can't rename them? Is there a way to test it?

Comment: I have a Hyper-V guest and a WSL machine running and still just 3 icons (all correct) so what you are seeing is indeed strange.  Have you run Windows Updates?

Comment: @HyperLel Normally it can, and like I said, I haven't experienced the issue since Win10 v17xx.